# How to claim an NFS persistent volume?

Tags: kubernetes, nfs, persistent-volumes

Being a beginner in kubernetes, I need:

A guide to the steps to be followed for creating a deployment, having claimed an nfs pv.
Please provide the yaml files to be applied in each step.

Sorry for being unclear, I have **UPDATED THE EXACT ISSUE HERE**:

[Why do we get the error 'Mount failed with exit status 32'? How to resolve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67887976/why-do-we-get-the-error-mount-failed-with-exit-status-32-how-to-resolve-this)

Answer (score 5):

You can find the documentation for the volume system at https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/. That explains how to set up an PVC and PV to bind to it. NFS doesn't directly support dynamic provisioning, so to start with you'll just want to make them by hand.

StackOverflow is not here to hand-hold you through basic documentation. If you have a specific question the docs don't answer, try asking that instead :)

Comment: Thanks, @coderanger for your response.
I have updated my exact issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67887976/why-do-we-get-the-error-mount-failed-with-exit-status-32-how-to-resolve-this